# plot_tiltedmaps isn't showing anything

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot 2 raster files but when I am using the `plot_tiltedmaps` function the plot is empty. I am following the steps in the 2nd [tutorial](https://github.com/marcosci/layer), called *More advanced example*. Any ideas why is that?

Here is the code:

```
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("marcosci/layer")
    
library(layer)
library(terra)

wd <- "path/"

pop = rast(paste0(wd, "pop.tif"))
agbh = rast(paste0(wd, "agbh.tif"))

pop <- tilt_map(pop, y_tilt = 3, x_shift = 25, y_shift = 50, parallel = TRUE)
agbh <- tilt_map(agbh, y_tilt = 3, x_shift = 50, y_shift = 100, parallel = TRUE)

map_list <- list(pop, agbh)

plot_tiltedmaps(map_list, palette = c("tofino", "rocket"), direction = c(-1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to increase a lot the `y_shift` value in the `tilt_map` function, like so:

```
library(layer)
library(terra)

agbh = rast("path/agbh.tif")
pop = rast("path/pop.tif")

tilt_landscape_1 <- tilt_map(agbh, parallel = TRUE)
tilt_landscape_2 <- tilt_map(pop, x_shift = 25, y_shift = 5000, parallel = TRUE)

map_list <- list(tilt_landscape_1, tilt_landscape_2)

plot_tiltedmaps(map_list,
                layer = c("value", "value"),
                palette = c("bilbao", "mako"))
```

[image: result]